# Is it difficult to get into graduate school for applied math with a computer science degree?

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics, computer-science, changing-fields

I'm a computer science student in my third year of undergrad. I've been taking math classes on the side and will have finished most of the applied math major by the time I graduate.

I'm wondering how difficult it would be to get into graduate school for applied math with a computer science undergrad degree. I could possibly switch over to the applied math major if that would make graduate school admissions easier, but I'm wondering if it would also be fairly possible with a computer science undergrad.

Comment: Will you be seeking a doctorate or just a MS?

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason why you couldn't get into an applied math graduate program with a CS bachelor's degree.  Some parts of some applied mathematics programs are called computer science in other programs (and vice versa).  Many applied mathematics students come from engineering, physics, CS, and other undergraduate programs.

Answer (score 3):

I did this myself (a long time ago, in the 1980's.) I completed the requirements for a BS in Mathematics and a BS in Computer Science, but I took the Computer Science degree because it was more employable.  A few years later after I'd had some experience in software development positions, I decided to go back to graduate school in applied mathematics.  I was accepted to every graduate program that I applied to.

Some key things to do:

1. Make sure in your application cover letter/statement of purpose to explain that you have taken a lot of mathematics at the undergraduate level.  This will help if the reader of the application doesn't bother to read your transcript and see the mathematics course work.
2. Get a good score on the GRE subject test in mathematics as well as on the GRE general tests.
3. Get letters of recommendation from your former mathematics professors, particularly professors in applied mathematics.
4. Connect your background in computer science to applied mathematics.  You're in a good position to specialize in numerical computing as a graduate student.